# Let $A$ be an abelian group. Show that $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb Z, A)$ is isomorphic to $A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Let $A$ be an abelian group. Show that $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb Z, A)$ is isomorphic to $A$.

My problem is figuring out how to define Φ and using it show the homomorphism between  $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb Z, A)$ and $A$.

Comment: Assuming $Z$ is the set of integers, I invite you to check that $ \varphi \in \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, A) \longmapsto \varphi(1)$ is the isomorphism you are seeking.

Comment: My problem is I'm having a hard time defining φ then showing the homomorphism to get started. I know once I do this, I will be able to show how its one to one and onto.

Comment: And yes Z is a set of integers.

Comment: @Lynn In the future, write what you're having trouble with in the question itself, rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

I see you are having problems in defining the homomorphism $\Phi:\mathrm{Hom}(\Bbb Z,A)\to A$, so let's deal with this in more detail. Note that $\Bbb Z$ is a group under addition $+$, and it is cyclic which means that there is an element, in this case the integer $1$, which generates each group element, i.e. every integer can be written as $1+1+\cdots+1$ or $-1-1-\cdots-1$. Now let $\phi:\Bbb Z\to A$ be a group homomorphism into an abelian group $A$. Then we have 
$$\phi(n)=\phi(\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_{n\text{ times}})=\underbrace{\phi(1)+\cdots+\phi(1)}_{n\text{ times}}=n\cdot\phi(1)$$ as $\phi$ respects the group operation. This implies that if two homomorphisms from the integers to $A$ map the $1$ to the same image, then they are equal. In other words, if we define $$\Phi:\mathrm{Hom}(\Bbb Z,A)\to A\\\phi\mapsto\phi(1)$$ then $\Phi$ is injective. Can you show that $\Phi$ is onto?

In order to show that $\Phi$ is a group homomorphism, you just need to check that $\Phi(\phi+\psi)=(\phi+\psi)(1)=\phi(1)+\psi(1)=\Phi(\phi)+\Phi(\psi)$, but this holds by the definition of the group structure on $\mathrm{Hom}(\Bbb Z,A)$